# Merge query in couchbase to to add append array in column

Tags: sql, database, couchbase, sql++

What I want to do is for every customer add a property named `orders` with the datatype `array<Order>[]` and move all `Orders` associated with a `Customer` into this property. In the target entity type and then delete the redundant property orders.person id afterwards.

I have done this so far:

```
MERGE INTO `Customers` AS cust
USING `Orders` AS ord ON cust.id = ord.personId

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET cust.orders = {"order_id": ord.id, "person_id": ord.person_id, "total_price": ord.total_price}
    WHERE cust.id = ord.PersonId
```

Comment: I am getting the Error which says this:

{
    "code": 5320,
    "msg": "Multiple UPDATE/DELETE of the same document (document key '46aef9cc-7068-4a4b-b0b3-b83f65820c46') in a MERGE statement"
  }

Answer (score 0):

Target row can't be mutated repeatedly.

```
MERGE INTO `Customers` AS cust
USING  (SELECT ord.personId, ARRAY_AGG({"order_id": ord.id,  "total_price": ord.total_price}) AS orders
        FROM `Orders` AS ord
        WHERE ........
        GROUP BY ord.personId) AS s
 ON cust.id = s.personId
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET cust.orders = s.orders
```